# MQ Queue MQTT_FIRST Trigger creating multiple trigger messages

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, mq

We have an Application MQ Queue marked as triggered and a MQTT_FIRST set on it.

When a message arrives into that queue for the first time the Queue Manager creates a trigger message and writes it into an initiation queue we defined for that purpose.
The trigger message fires up the execution of a monitoring process that will start a trigger-monitor application which will go and read messages from the application queue one by one.

We use Spring JmsTemplate  to read messages one by one from the application queue. That jmsTemplate instance opens a connection to the application queue, reads  a message from there and then closes the connection.

The problem we have is that when the connection is closed if there are multiple messages in the Application queue a new trigger message will be sent to the initiation queue which will cause another trigger-monitor application (running on a different host) to pop up. This is not what we want as for us it is essential to have only one message consumer active at the same time as message sequence is very important.

The reason we have multiple trigger-monitor applications (or consumers) is for a HA reason.

So my question is: Is there a way to prevent MQ manager to send multiple MQTT_FIRST trigger messages to the initiation queue and make it only send it once when a message arrives in an empty queue and that is it. If we really wanted a message trigger being sent again we can use the Trigger Interval for this but for what we are trying to achieve there should be no more than one trigger message in the initiation queue no matter what.

Thank in advance
Julian

Answer (score 0):

> The problem we have is that when the connection is closed if there are
>   multiple messages in the Application queue a new trigger message will
>   be sent to the initiation queue which will cause another
>   trigger-monitor application (running on a different host) to pop up.

.

> Is there a way to prevent MQ manager to send multiple MQTT_FIRST
>   trigger messages to the initiation queue and make it only send it once
>   when a message arrives in an empty queue and that is it.

Yes, don't close the connection.  You need to read the rules when using Trigger First.  One of the rules is to consume ALL of the messages before closing the connection.  If you don't follow the rules then you can't complain.

Comment: I am not complaining. I am looking for a solution in the context of the existing rules. 
When you get thousands of messages in a big batch it is impractical to process them all in one go for various reasons: time outs, getting the transaction too big, etc

Comment: You may need to rethink on the design.  Trigger first doesnt look like the correct solution in this context. You can try trigger by depth if transaction size is a concern.

Comment: The simplest solution is to greatly reduce your batch window.  i.e. instead of once every 6 hours, run it every hour or every 20 minutes.

Comment: @nsupathy you were right. MQTT_FIRST did not do the job for us. Shame that IBM guys did not provided us with a flag to tell Queue Manager I only want that trigger to fire when I get the first message and no other time. As long as I am listening to the initiation queue continuously IBM should not care how I read the messages from my application queue. In other words "You told me I got a message let me to deal with them as I want and only tell me again I got messages if I go away from the initiation queue not from the application queue". Nice to have in addition to the actual rules.

Comment: @Roger you assume we wait for a batch to build up and then start consuming it. This is false as we want to process the message ASAP. I pointed out we are after a HA solution. Why we need this trigger because we want our "competing" MDBs to only run once at a time and such we made them listen to the initiation queue rather than to the application queue so once a message arrives it will be only one MDB to process it. If an MDB goes down there would be some others to take over the load while maintaining message sequence.

Comment: I ended up by adding a MQTT_DEPTH that fairs when queue depth equals to 1. The challenge was that after firing up the triggering on that queue is switched off. I had to switch it back on at the end of processing with PCFMessage.